# jquery.countdown.js giving really off results.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really pressed for time so I am going to ask on here.  The time of writing this is 2012-10-06.  I am trying use a a jquery plugin called /jquery.countdown.js".   It seems pretty straight forward.
Can Anyone see what I am doing wrong?  I am just trying test a countdown till tomorrow.

```
     <script>
             $(function(){
            var d = new Date(2012, 10, 07, 15, 4);
              $('#compact').countdown({until:d , compact: true,
                description: ''});

                    });

                    </script>
```

it  returns 32 days ++
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months are 0 based, not 1 based (January is month 0).  Tomorrow's date would be:

```
  var d = new Date(2012, 9, 7, 15, 4);
```

Since you are asking for November, 7, 2012 it is returning correctly that it is 32 days away.

Comment: Thanks man , If I had thought about it, I would have realized...0 based